# Flutter Firebase: How to compare two fields' number value from firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Basically, I want to compare the number value in 'Latitude' field and 'CurrLatitude' field (they are both saved in firebase), if they are not matched, the alarm will be triggered.

As you can see from line 186, I realised that the comparison is within the 'String' but not the 'number' value. So, I wonder how should I solve this?

[image: Flutter code]
[image: 'Latitude' and 'CurrLatitude' in Firebase]

```
class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  User? user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
  UserModel loggedInUser = UserModel();
  final loc.Location location = loc.Location();
  StreamSubscription<loc.LocationData>? _locationSubscription;
  CollectionReference users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');
  int alarmId = 1;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("users")
        .doc(user!.uid)
        .get()
        .then((value) {
      this.loggedInUser = UserModel.fromMap(value.data());
      setState(() {});
      _requestPermission();
      location.changeSettings(interval: 300, accuracy: loc.LocationAccuracy.high);
      location.enableBackgroundMode(enable: true);
    });
  }


@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue[50],
        title: const Text("TrackingSystem"),
        titleTextStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Container(child: Column (children: [
 Expanded(
      child: FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
      future: users.doc(user!.uid).get(),
      builder:
          (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          Map<String, dynamic> data = snapshot.data!.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
          return Text("Current Location: ${data['currlatitude']},  ${data['currlongitude']}");
                    }
          return Text(" ");
          }))])));
      }

  getLocation() async {
    try {
      final loc.LocationData _locationResult = await location.getLocation();
      await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(user!.uid).set({
        'currlatitude': _locationResult.latitude,
        'currlongitude': _locationResult.longitude,
      }, SetOptions(merge: true));
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

  Future<void> _listenLocation() async {
    _locationSubscription = location.onLocationChanged.handleError((onError) {
      print(onError);
      _locationSubscription?.cancel();
      setState(() {
        _locationSubscription = null;
      });
    }).listen((loc.LocationData currentlocation) async {
      await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(user!.uid).set({
        'currlatitude': currentlocation.latitude,
        'currlongitude': currentlocation.longitude,
      }, SetOptions(merge: true));
    });
    
    if ('latitude' == 'currlatitude') {
                    if ('longitude' == 'currlongitude') {
                      AndroidAlarmManager.periodic(
                    Duration(seconds: 0), alarmId, stopAlarm);
                    }
                    else {
                      AndroidAlarmManager.periodic(
                    Duration(seconds: 0), alarmId, fireAlarm);
                    }
                  }
    else {
                    AndroidAlarmManager.periodic(
                    Duration(seconds: 2), alarmId, fireAlarm);
                  }
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In statement like this you are comparing constant strings:

```
if (('latitude') == ('currLatitude')) {
```

The string `'latitude'` is **never** going to equal to the string `'currLatitude'`.

What you probably want to do is:

1. [Read the document](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage#one-time-read) where you have *values* for these fields with `get()`.
2. Then get those field values from the document.
3. Compare the resulting field values in your code instead.

Comment: But the return value is always in Text form. How can I get the field values in terms of Double? And how should I list it for comparison?

Comment: Since you store the field values as numbers, the SDK will return them as numbers. If that is not happening for you, edit your question to show how you read the values.

Comment: I have added more codes into my question already but not a complete one. Please have a look. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to compare two varibales which have the value of lat & long, but comparing String variable isn't logic.
Then you can do the goal of what you want.

Comment: Can you provide more detail ideas for me to proceed this? I have no clue and stucked on this for few days already..